# SQL Query to order 2 different tables with a similar attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 2 tables, they both have a structure similar to this one

```
id | content | date
```

However I would like to a make a query where the 2 tables are mixed together and ordered by their date

for example in the TABLE_A I've (1,Joe,20-11-2020)/(2,John,20-11-2021) TABLE_B has (1,Luke,20-11-2010)/(1,Mark,20-11-2011) The result I want to see is: (1,Luke,20-11-2010)/(1,Mark,20-11-2011)/(1,Joe,20-11-2020)/(2,John,20-11-2021)

Comment: Please be more precise: Show sample input for both tables, expected outcome and which queries you tried so far. Your description sounds like you just need UNION (ALL) and ORDER BY.

Comment: Sure, for example in the TABLE_A I've (1,Joe,20-11-2020)/(2,John,20-11-2021)
TABLE_B has (1,Luke,20-11-2010)/(1,Mark,20-11-2011)
The result I want to see is:
(1,Luke,20-11-2010)/(1,Mark,20-11-2011)/(1,Joe,20-11-2020)/(2,John,20-11-2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT T.ID,T.CONTENT,T.DATE
 FROM TABLE_1 AS T
   UNION ALL
 SELECT A.ID,A.CONTENT,A.DATE
 FROM TABLE_2 AS A
 ORDER BY 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select id, content, date
from (
select id, content, date
from tab_A
union all
select id, content, date
from tab_B
) C order by date
```

use "union" instead of "union all" if you are not interest to have duplicates rows